# Destination file that reflects source folders grunt

Tags: javascript, file, gruntjs, concatenation

sorry if the name of this thread is a bit weird. It's hard to explain in one line.

Basically, this is what I want my folder setup to look like:

```
                html5
                  |
   src-----------------------build------_config
    |                           |           |
  master                      master    Gruntfiles etc
    |                           |
css-images-js-index.html        |
 |    |    |                    |
.css .jpg .js                   |
                                |
                           .css .jpg .js
```

From my root folder (html5) I have a src and a build folder. In both of them, there will be a lot of more folders than the master folder, all of which will have the same layout (different formats). What I basically want to happen, is I want the content in the src > master folder to be flattened into the corresponding build > master folder. I've tried the flatten option shown [here](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically), however, that flattens the entire thing, causing the contents of the master folder to be put straight in the build folder, which is not what I want. I've been messing some with the rename function, but it seems overly complicated for this task. Is there no other way to do this?

EDIT: I have this task:

```
    copy: {
        images: {
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    flatten: true,
                    cwd: "../src/",
                    src: ["**"],
                    dest: "../build/master",
                    filter: "isFile"
                },
            ]
        }
    },
```

Which does exactly what it's supposed to do. **However**, I really need the destination folder "master" to be dynamic. It should not be hard-coded like it is right now. It needs to be the corresponding folder that was copied from the src folder. It doesn't work to put "**" there unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe better to take a ready-made solution? for example - https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine `cwd` with `flatten` (and `dest`) to flatten just what you want, just where you want.
As you don't know the name of your folders, you have to use a custom task to get the list of folders, and then generate and run a `copy` target for each:

```
  grunt.registerTask('myCopy', function() {
    var srcFolder = 'src';
    var dstFolder = 'dest';

    var fs = require('fs');
    var path = require('path');
    var srcpath = path.resolve(__dirname, srcFolder);
    var folders = fs.readdirSync(srcpath).filter(function(file) {
      return fs.statSync(path.join(srcpath, file)).isDirectory();
    });
    folders.forEach(function(f){
      grunt.config.set("copy." + f, {
        files : [{
            expand: true,
            flatten: true,
            cwd: srcFolder + '/' + f,
            src: '**',
            dest: dstFolder + '/' + f,
            filter: 'isFile',
        }]
      });
      grunt.task.run('copy:' + f);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention in the post that I will not know the names of the "master" folders. There will be multiple randomly named folders adjacent to the master folder. Could I instead switch "master" with "**"?

Comment: Update: It does not work to change the dest "master" folder to "\*\*". This creates a folder named "\*\*"..

Comment: OK, there is no built-in way of doing that, but you can use a custom task to generate a list of copy targets for each "master", then run these. I've updated my answer

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. I thought this sort of thing might be built in to Grunt, but I can see how normally, you would have a separate project for every src / build folder. Thanks a bunch!